# send multiple arguments using apply function

Tags: r

Hi I'm trying to use apply on a matrix I call eq; What I like to do is to send a function I made with multiple arguments.  Currently when I do this it works:

```
apply(eq, 1, manydo2)

manydo2 <-function(x){   # do something with the vector x  }
```

however when I try something like this

```
apply(list("x1"=eq, "r1" = 18), 1, manydo2)
```

it fails, is there anyway I can pass the row data as well as some other variable say r1 in this case? multiple thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Do you want to subset the matrix or do you want to pass other arguments to eq?

Comment: Use `apply` with an array, a matrix or a data frame. Use `lapply` for a list: `lapply(list("x1"=eq, "r1" = 18), manydo2)`.

Comment: @JohnPaul sorry for abstraction.  I'm trying to pass a subset of eq to the function manydo2 but with multiple arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to pass the row, and a single argument that is the same for each row:

```
manydo3 <- function(x, r1) NULL
apply(eq, 1, manydo3, r1=18)
```

If you want different values for the second argument for each row, then you want to split your matrix into rows and pass both the rows and your other argument with `mapply`:

```
mapply(manydo3, split(eq, row(eq)), R)
```

where `length(R) == nrow(eq)` (i.e. R contains r1, r2, etc).

Comment: This, plus if you like you can subset `eq`, such as `apply(eq[eq$colx==x1,], 1, manydo, r1=18)`. If you look at `?apply` you will see it has a `...` argument, which means you can add other arguments and they will get sent to the function you called in `apply`.

Comment: Hi BrodieG and John, yes this works perfectly; I ended up using something like this `apply(eq[1:5,1:17],1,manydo2,r1=18)` and it works, so thank you much!